# ¿Cómo extender de un layout u otro dependiendo una condición? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo 3 tipos de usuarios diferentes, por lo que, para cada uno tengo un header distinto. Estoy intentando detectar el tipo de usuario y extender del header correspondiente, pero el if, elseif y else no me funcionaron (se mostraban los 3 header al mismo tiempo).

Luego de leer un poco, probé con un operador ternario dentro de @extends y ha funcionado, pero solo me sirve para dos casos ¿cómo puedo hacerlo para tres casos?

```
@extends(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin') == 'admin' ? 'layouts.admin' : 'layouts.userA')
```

Otro intento:

**- En /app/User.php:**

```
public function hasAnyRoleName($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                return $role;
            }
        }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return $role;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
```

**- En mi blade home**

```
@switch(Auth::user()->hasAnyRoleName('admin', 'user1', 'user2'))
    @case('admin')
        @extends('layouts.admin')
        @break
    @case('user1')
        @extends('layouts.userA')
        @break
    @default
        @extends('layouts.userB')
@endswitch
```

**NOTA: Tampoco me funcionó**

Answer (score 0):

```
@extends(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin') == 'admin' ? 'layouts.admin' : 'layouts.userA')
```

Esta expresión no es mas que un if normal (como tu bien dices ternario), que se podria traducir en un if normal

```
@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin') == 'admin')
    @extends('layouts.admin')
@else
    @extends('layouts.userA')
@endif
```

Simplemente anida los if en lugar de ponerlos separados o usa un switch

Anidados

```
@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin') == 'admin')
    @extends('layouts.admin')
@else
    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin') == 'user')
        @extends('layouts.userA')
    @else
        @extends('layouts.guest')
    @endif
@endif
```

Switch

```
@switch(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
    @case('admin')
        @extends('layouts.admin')
        @break

    @case('user')
        @extends('layouts.userA')
        @break

    @default
        @extends('layouts.guest')
@endswitch
```

Comment: Exacto, pero como comenté en mi pregunta inicial, si uso IF, ELSEIF y ELSE, por alguna razón que yo desconozco se añaden todos los headers. He copiado y pegado tu switch y el resultado es el mismo. ¿Tienes idea de porque sucede esto?

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto: https://tim.hithlonde.com/t/laravel-conditional-with-extends , así que la pregunta es ¿cómo hago un operador ternario con 3 opciones? probablemente no se pueda, así que la pregunta sería ¿cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Se de sobra que pasa, pero no es lo que preguntas. el trait `hasRole`devuelve un true o un false pero tu lo estas comparando con con una cadena. Igualmente el código solo te mostrara un header, si no es así el problema lo tienes en la construcción de tu layout

Comment: Voy a añadir a mi pregunta un segundo intento, haciendo uso de tu swith. (Tampoco me funcionó)

Comment: compañero, no sé si sea correcto, pero lo he solucionado cambiado "extends" por "include". Gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: Inlcude lo que hace es copiar una parte de código, pero extend te permite usar section y yield

Answer (score 0):

1. Al usar **hasRole** preguntas por su rol directamente es decir `hasRole('admin')`, `hasRole('user')` y dependiendo de la respuesta sabras si posee o no el role.
2. **hasRole** devuelve *true* o *false*, no el nombre del rol que posee el usuario
3. Deberías asegurarte si el usuario esta Loggeado, utilizando `Auth::user()` te devolvera *true* si el existe un usuario logeado o *false* si no existe el usuario.

Para un if ternario de blade usa esto

```
@extends(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') ? 'layouts.admin' : (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('user') ? 'layouts.userA' : 'layouts.guest'))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Al final he decidido crear un sólo header y extenderlo en todos lados, luego, internamente decidido que opciones mostrar dependiendo del rol

Comment: Que bueno hayas solucionado...